# add/delete listgrid by clicking +/- image button

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I need a listgrid with `+/-` button so that I can use these buttons for adding or deleting list grid.

```
ListGrid listGrid = new ListGrid();
listGrid.setWidth(230);  
listGrid.setHeight(224);  
listGrid.setDataSource(coursesDS);
listGrid.setCanDragRecordsOut(true);  
listGrid.setDragDataAction(DragDataAction.COPY);
```

In this way only listgrid will be created, but is there any implicity functionality for increment listgrid by providing button specific to listgrid?

Or I need to create explicitly image button and have to write code so that I can add number of listgrids when click on image(add) button?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Regarding the "-" icon:

  ```
  listGrid.setCanRemoveRecords(true);
  ```

  Creates an additional rightmost column with "-" icon to remove the current row of the listGrid.
- The closest I could find to "+" is in this example:
  http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_editing_new_row

  ```
  listGrid.startEditingNew();
  ```

  in the example the line is executed from onClick function inside ClickHandler for additional button.